How should I migrate this from TFS to Git
I'm in the process of migrating repos from TFS to Git, till now I've managed to transfer simple solution repo (just main one) but Now I'm in the situation where I've the following TFS situation

Release folder is empty, so no problem.
The issue is that I've the GIT history migrated for the PostProcessor folder (if I do right click on folder, then View history), but I'm not able to see the history for Main branch and Utility folders.
I've used Git-tfs with clone function without any particular parameter passed. Which is the best way to migrate those kind of projects?

Based on your screenshot and description, you need to migrate the TFVC repo to Git Repo.
You can consider using the following steps:
Step1: Run the script: git tfs clone <TFS URL> $/project/folder (The repo type is tfvc). Then you could clone the project and all history.
Step2: Run cd repo path to navigate to the local repo path and git checkout -b customBranch   to create a temp branch.
Step3: Run git remote add origin <Git URL> to set the target.
For example: git remote add origin http://ADOSever:8080/tfs/Collection2017/Project1/_git/3 (The repo type is git)
Step4: Run git push --set-upstream origin CustomBranch to push all repos to the temp branch.
Result:
You can check the history of the folders in the Azure Repo -> History. Based on my test, it contains all related history.
For example:

If you need to migrate other folders or branches, you can create a new Azure DevOps Git Repo to store it.

Thank Kevin, this is what I've done, but in some case the repo structure on TFS has been messed .. it can be that I've a TFS folder with inside a branch (Main icon on my screenshot) then a folder, so when I migrate the root (PostProcessor in my case) I got mixed changeset. But I think it's normal..probably migrating to two different folder would help

@advapi yes. You idea should be correct. You can split the root and branch to two folders. When you migrate the branch, you can add the argument: --branches=all to git tfs command, it will include all related history. For example: git tfs clone --branches=all  collectionurl $/project/branchname

This part is working I've issue with another branch that's looking and failing..I've opened another ticket

@advapi Glad to know that this part can work fine now.
